# Is there anyway using html5 to force android/ios virtual keyboard to be shown

Tags: android, html, angularjs

I have some html forms that when they get rendered I would like the keyboard to appear without the user having to touch the field first.  I have tried using click and focus neither brings up the keyboard.

For what its worth I am using angular.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible with out a very kludgy work around. You might be able to have a hidden text field that it set to focus, which would bring up the keyboard and then manually set focus on other items in the view when needed. However this might cause some issues and you might be able to see the cursor in the hidden text field, among other issues. Why do you need the keyboard to be displayed without a focus on some field?